# Dtrace not displaying stacks on Mac

Tags: mac-osx, node.js, dtrace

I'm on OSx Yosemite and i'm playing with Node.js CPU profiling. However i can't get DTrace to display the stack traces. I'm suspecting a problem with `jstack/ustack`.

So if i do a DTrace at 97Hz:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'profile-97/pid == 54308/{ @[jstack(80, 8192)] = count(); }' -c "sleep 30" > dtrace.out
```

This is the output i get:

```
 node`0x40
  1

node`0x18b6160
  1

node`0x71361a61
  1

node`0x83fe8c79
  1

node`0xa845d679
  1

node`0x86ea4389
  1

  4
```

This is obviously not the output i would like to get since i can't see any details here.

Anything obvious i am misssing? or any alternatives?

Comment: Can you get stack traces from other processes?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I just tried dtracing sublime and adobe reader and i get the same output. No stack traces.

Comment: Maybe this applies:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11

Comment: Nope. I am not using ElCapitan